# Send data from Textview in one fragment to another fragment which are in two different activities

Tags: android, android-fragments

How can I use the text in textview in one fragment in mainactivity from another fragment in another activity(activity_main2) .

Answer (score 1):

Basically you will have your `FirstFragment` communicate with your `MainActivity`, your `MainActivity` with your `OtherActivity`, and your `OtherActivity` with your `SecondFragment`. For the specifics see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38872936/3356270)!

Comment: I tried doing it in different way i made my textview static and i am able to use it throughout my app.It's working.But is it  wrong way to do so.If why.

Comment: This is a case of strong coupling of components and considered bad practice. The whole point of fragments and also one of the points of activities is that each component should be independent of others of its kind (fragments independent of other fragments and activities independent of other activities). This gives you the opportunity, for example, to show only one fragment on a small screen (smartphones) while the other fragment is not even created yet AND show these two fragments side by side on a larger screen (tablets). Static references between fragments break this kind of loose coupling.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass [extras](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra(java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle)) between activities.

Then, in your MainActivity, add:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Activity_main2.class);
intent.putExtra("EXTRA_KEY_TEXT", "myText");
startActivity(intent);
```

And add to your Activity_main2:

```
String textFromMainActivity = getIntent().getStringExtra("EXTRA_KEY_TEXT");
```

Hope it helps you!

Comment: I tried doing it in different way i made my textview static and i am able to use it throughout my app.It's working.But is it  wrong way to do so.If why.